# Related model cannot be resolved

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 1.8b1

There are two models in two apps called `accounts` and `products`

```
products/models.py
class ChecklistEnterpriseType(models.Model):
    checklist_enterprise_type = models.CharField('Type of Enterprise', max_length=50, choices=zip(ENTERPRISE_CHOICES, ENTERPRISE_CHOICES))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.checklist_enterprise_typ
```

And the another model is

```
accounts/models.py
class sample(models.Model):
    enterprise_type = models.ForeignKey(ChecklistEnterpriseType, related_name='enterprise_type')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.enterprise_type
```

When I do `python manage.py makemigrations`, it will add the migration file. But when I do `python manage.py migrate` it raises me the error like:

```
raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.rel.to)
ValueError: Related model u'products.ChecklistEnterpriseType' cannot be resolved
```

How can I resolve this.

Appreciated the answers :)

Comment: What order are the apps listed in  your INSTALLED_APPS settings?

Comment: @mishbah order is INSTALLED_APPS = ('accounts', 'products',)

Comment: Try swapping that. As you are importing models from products into accounts..

Comment: @mishbah Not working buddy

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback? Does the migration file in `accounts` have `products` listed as a dependency?

Comment: I answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586373/valueerror-related-model-umutech-branch-cannot-be-resolved/35533506#35533506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line:

```
 checklist_enterprise_type = models.CharField('Type of Enterprise', max_length=50, choices=zip(ENTERPRISE_CHOICES, ENTERPRISE_CHOICES))
```

**Should Be:**

```
 checklist_enterprise_type = models.CharField(verbose_name='Type of Enterprise', max_length=50, choices=zip(ENTERPRISE_CHOICES, ENTERPRISE_CHOICES))
```

Comment: nope.. Got an unexpected keyword argument error on placing the verbose

Comment: sorry my bad, it's verbose_name. And make sure you imported ChecklistEnterpriseType

Comment: Same related model cannot be resolved error raising even after adding verbose_name

Comment: `verbose_name` is also the first positional argument, so this is unnecessary.

Comment: @knbk It's been a very long gap you answered this question. But somehow this works for me at this point. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A very delayed response... but I just had a similar issue that was very hard to track down, but eventually did, so am putting a pointer here in case anyone else gets hit by it. I was adding testing to a several year old Django webapp, and found that ./manage.py test was failing. I had never run `./manage.py` migrate on an empty database!

At some stage in the early days of Django 1.7 migrations were generated that had failed circular dependency detection, so you could update from a newer version but not the first migrations. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22319 for the bug report.

I still had to work out how to fix it without throwing away all my migrations and generating them fresh.

So to fix, I went through all the migrations (it was only 5 affected files). Some models were required by earlier migrations, but they weren't included due to individual fields depending on later migrations. So I brought the whole `migrations.CreateModel` for the model back to an earlier migration, but took those fields and used `migrations.AddField` in the later migration (where the model had been put originally).

Hopefully that explains it, but if anyone runs into this issue sometime in the future, feel free to comment if it needs further elaboration.

Comment: Thanks! This clued me in to the fix for my codebase (for future readers your solution may be one or the other depending on the state of your migrations).

I was unable to move `migrations.CreateModel` to an earlier migration because it was already in the earliest, unapplied migration. In my case this was because a new migration in another app also depended on this new model, but it didn't include the migration that created the model as a dependency.

So the solution is to check for any missing dependencies in any newly generated migrations, especially if you have multiple at once.