# ValueError: Related model u'mutech.branch' cannot be resolved

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-models

I am trying to make foreign key in my models.py file. But on running python manage.py migrate command i got the below error, previously every thing was fine. Even i have undo all my changes it still giving same error,I have also tried deleting my database but nothing works.

```
          Applying mutech.0004_sub_branch...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/rahul/mydjangoapp/jango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .

      File "/home/rahul/mydjangoapp/jango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1414, in resolve_related_fields
        raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.rel.to)
    ValueError: Related model u'mutech.branch' cannot be resolved
```

> models.py file-

```
from django.db import models

class branch(models.Model):
    branch_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __str__ on Python 3
            return str(self.branch_title)   

class project(models.Model):
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    project_desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_duration = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(branch)

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
            return str(self.project_title)
```

> view.py file is -

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from mutech.models import *

def project_info(request):
    project_list = project.objects.all()
    branch_list = branch.objects.all()
    context = {'project_list':project_list , 'branch_list':branch_list }
    return render(request, 'mutech/project.html', context)

def project_branch_info(request):
    branch_list = branch.objects.all()
    context = {'branch_list':branch_list }
    return render(request, 'mutech/project_branch_info.html', context)
```

Comment: check if there is another var/model with name branch, also, u should use capitals. Branch.

Comment: thanks for answering, but there is only one branch class in model.py file

Comment: Could you post your migration files, please?

Comment: hello @ knbk ,Please tell me what is migration files and how can i get it.

Comment: I have tried deleting 'branch' table and all tables which are dependent on it. That is there is no branch in my project 'mutech' but still it is giving same error as - 'mutech.branch' cannot be resolved

Comment: Your migration files are all the files in your `mutech/migrations/` folder. If there is no such folder, try running `python manage.py makemigrations mutech` and rerun `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution which worked for me is to delete my migrations folder and database completely thereafter running following commands-

> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> python manage.py migrate

because this error occured to me due to some misplacement of foreign key, and I was getting the error even after undoing the changes.

We are deleting the migration folder in the app because the actual problem is with that folder and there is nothing special in migration folder and it will be recreated using your model.py file  running the command -*python manage.py makemigrations*. The solution is just to delete the Migration folder and recreate it using commands.

So what you have to do-

1. Delete migration folder from the app.
2. Run the commands *python manage.py makemigrations* and then *python manage.py migrate*

> Caution: The data in the database will be lost after this, So perform this only if your data is not important.

Comment: When I tried this, it responded to "python manage.py makemigrations" with "No changes detected".

Comment: Hello @rossdavidh! I guess you have not deleted the migration folder so first delete it and then try the "python manage.py makemigrations" command again.If still it does not work then also try deleting both migration folder and database and then run command.

Comment: I had the same issue, but it appears that evan though it displays that message, the migrations are done anyway

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this problem:

1. Create a new `ForeignKey` call `tmp` to your related model. Run a migration.
2. Delete the old `ForeignKey` and run a migration.
3. Rename `tmp` to whatever the old `ForeignKey` was called. Run a migration.

So, you end up having three migration files to do one thing but at least it does it!

Comment: Wouldn't it lead to data loss upon migration?

Comment: @texnic It worked for me. Your mileage might vary… ⍨

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by cyclic dependency in your migrations. Some other migration that is run prior to the latest migration is calling a migration that reinstates the state before model rename. For example, you renamed model `foo` to `bar` in `xyzzy.migrations.0004_rename` but during applying migrations, after `xyzzy.migrations.0004_rename` runs `bozotic.0002_bozo` that depends on `xyzzy.migrations.0001_initial` thus the migration that has to be applied now doesn't see the state created by `xyzzy.migrations.004_rename`.

Took me an hour to debug and fix this error in my project.

Check your migration dependencies and try manually adjusting dependencies so that when running the migration models are in the desired state

Comment: This is very similar to my problem: In an existing project with twelve apps and hundreds of migrations, I tried to add a new model with `ForeignKey` to `app_x.ModelX`. This added a dependency on `app_x.migrations.0043`, which suddenly prevented tests from running due to the `Related model ... cannot be resolved` error. Turns out somewhere in (ancient) `app_x.migrations.0027` there was a reference to a renamed model, but the rename-migration was not listed as dependency. Never gave us any trouble until today... Fixing that dependency seems to do the job.